# AppleScript - How to get a folder's first child path (only when the first child is a folder, not a file)?

Tags: applescript, parent-child

How do you get a folder's first child path (when the first child is a folder)?

Say you have...

```
Folder 1 ¬
  File 1
  File 2
  Folder 2 ¬
    File A
    File B
    File C
    File D
```

**Use case:**

I select a batch of folders, all on the same level as `Folder 1` with:
`set foldersToProcess to choose folder with multiple selections allowed`

Then, I loop through each each of the queued folder `foldersToProcess`, where in the process I want to look into the first child folder of `Folder 1` (being `Folder 2`), every single time.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **try block** because maybe some of the chosen folders doesn't contain subfolders at all. So, without try block it will throw error when asking for folder 1 of empty list.

To get first folders as System Event's **folder references**:

```
set chosenFolders to (choose folder with multiple selections allowed)

set firstFolders to {}
repeat with anAlias in chosenFolders
    try
        tell application "System Events" to ¬
            set end of firstFolders to folder 1 of folder (anAlias as text)
    end try
end repeat
```

To get **HFS paths** of first folders, edit corresponding code line with:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
            set end of firstFolders to path of folder 1 of folder (anAlias as text)
```

To get **Posix paths** of first folders,edit corresponding code line with:

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
            set end of firstFolders to POSIX path of folder 1 of folder (anAlias as text)
```